# Como usar fonte Helvetica ou outra em um site, e fazer aparecer qualquer PC?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou com problema de fonte em um site, eu estou usando  Helvetica, mas em outros PCs que não têm essa fonte ela não aparece. Como fazer pra todos verem com essa fonte?

Comment: Você precisa ter uma [licença](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/helvetica/webfont_preview.html) da versão web da fonte.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`font-face`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) para incorporá-la em seu site. Contudo ela é uma fonte paga, pra usá-la você deve comprá-la ou usar uma similar (do [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts), por exemplo).

Comment: então eu vo usar fontes gratuitas mas que não tem no windows, mas não sei com puxar ela no css, pra ela rodar em outros pcs que não tem ela ,como faço?

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda